# Trash isn't showing deleted files from my other partitions

Tags: partitioning, delete, trash

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 and I'm having a problem: deleting a file from another partition doesn't show up in Trash like it used to be. Trash only show files deleted from the partition that the system is installed. When I delete a file, the Undo button doesn't work. I can access my files by pressing Control+H, to show hidden files, then going to .Trash-1000.

How do I restore the previous behavior? I tested on a Xubuntu live USB and deleting file behavior is normal.

[I saw a report of this problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+bug/1633824), but there is showing that the bug was fixed.

Thanks!

Comment: Please try this: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: Thanks, George, but I had to revert to 16.04. I faced this issue after a fresh install and always after an installation I let the system update everything. :/